# Import from Three.js example error - Relative > module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning from Three.js excamples and nothing is working for base thing like Import function for js files. I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “three”. Relative
> module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

in browsers (Firefox, Chrome).

The full code is below but the line with problems (info from browsers) is:
import * as THREE from 'three';
It is line from excample:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<base href="./">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
</style>

<body>
<!-- <script src="./src/three.js"></script> -->

<div class="">
</div>


<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "./src/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="module" >
//IT IS LINE below WITH PROBLEM!
    import * as THREE from 'three';
//    import * as THREE from './src/three.module.js' // I tried it but doesn't work too
    
    import { OBJLoader } from './src/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
    import { MTLLoader } from './src/loaders/MTLLoader.js';
    
    window.lastLoadedObj;
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    
    // instantiate a loader
    const loader = new OBJLoader();

    // load a resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        './obj/test1/dresser.obj',
        // called when resource is loaded
        function ( object ) {

            scene.add( object );
            window.lastLoadedObj = object;

        },
        // called when loading is in progresses
        function ( xhr ) {

            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {

            console.log( 'An error happened' );

        }
    );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to "./", ".", "/", I also made import with "query":
import * as THREE from './src/three.module.js'

and I am lack of another ideas.